# Fetch image from mysql database to android by image path

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Im currently creating an android app which includes the image gallery. But im having a hard time when trying to fetch images from my database. I save the path of my image and trying to save it to json then parse it to my android.
Here's my code :

photo.php

photo.php

```
  <?php

define('HOST','');
define('USER','');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','');
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

// query the application data
$sql = "SELECT image FROM photos";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$rows[]=$row;

}

// close the database connection
mysqli_close($con);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

FetchImage.java

```
 public class FetchImage extends Activity {
Button load_img;
ImageView img;
Bitmap bitmap;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fecth_image);
    load_img = (Button)findViewById(R.id.load);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    load_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             new LoadImage().execute("http://iguideph-001-site1.btempurl.com/PhotoUpload/uploads/vigan1.jpg");
        }
    });


}
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FetchImage.this);
       // pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
       // pDialog.show();

    }
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
         try {
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

         if(image != null){
         img.setImageBitmap(image);
         pDialog.dismiss();

         }else{

         pDialog.dismiss();
         Toast.makeText(FetchImage.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     }
 }

  }
```

activity_fetch_image.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/load"
    android:text="Load Image" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/img"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please anyone help me :)

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? can you elaborate more on your problem? It seems like you're having trouble with the Json Parsing, if that's so, please post the JSON and what have you tried to parse it. If it gives an error/exception, posting the exception would help too